# print env vars in production with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

I am debugging env vars with Laravel 8 in production.

In local, I have no problem.

In production, when I do:

```
dd(env('DB_CONNECTION'),
```

I get null, but my app works, which means it is connecting to the DB.

Why isn't it working ?

I tried to clear all caches with `php artisan optimize`, with no success.

Any idea ?

Comment: Access it through the cache instead. Env variables are not accessible when they have been cached.

Comment: See the note in the documentation, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching